# Get the value from a single field from my firebase db

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Well using Koltlin i'm trying to do a very simple thing, so i thought...
i want to set a textview.text with the value of the "file" field i stored in firebase database. this is my database :

[image]

I get the single user related content but like this

```
key - enGKzLMIE0czXUWrcUeCnfKLQ7r1 value: {file=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lci9project.appspot.com/o/Avatars%2Fde4d49b5-20e7-4801-80d0-2458aafc5d23?alt=media&token=ffd9ab4f-73c7-49b5-9090-b2c5ff05e3e1, userid=Lasyyyl}
```

with this code:

```
val uidref= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users/$uidref")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val key = dataSnapshot.getKey()
                val value = dataSnapshot.getValue()
               println("key - $key value: $value")
```

But i cant seem to get just the "file" value ...

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly how your database is structured.  It looks like you tried to attach a picture, but formatted the text incorrectly.

Comment: well it is the firebase storage path, and if you follow that link it will display a image, but besides that. i need to have whatever is in the individual field. it can be the userid ... i need to get the "Lasyyyl " part of the result im getting know

Comment: I understand that you have a URL to an image.  I don't understand the exact structure of your database.

Comment: What link? Seems broken

Comment: it seems something append to the image with db i used sorry.. this is my db.....https://imgur.com/k41ND5E

Comment: Please don’t include images (or external links) in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of the file change the following:

```
val value = dataSnapshot.getValue()
```

Into this:

```
val value = dataSnapshot.child("file").getValue(String::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the file Strong there are 2 options

```
datasnapshot.getChild("file").getValue(String.class)
```

Or you can just ask for the file attribute

```
...reference.child("users/$uidref").child("file")
//You can also "users/$uidref/file"
```